# How to end do not disturb mode?

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow

Not able to end the do not disturb mode. Tried clicking the 'end now' tab repeatedly, doesn't work. Neither there's anything in the settings nor in the slide down quick settings.

It's getting inconvenient to check the notifications, as the mode says 'priority only'. What are the solutions?

Comment: What does repeatedly pushing the Volume up button does?

Comment: Just flashes an 'end now' tab but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Greetings! Sincerely hope (and, quite likely!) you have already figured it out. Here, hoping it would help others with this same query, a simpler solution —

- Simply **pull down the volume** to *vibrate*
- Then, pull it down **once more** to *silent*
- And, then, just **pull it up again** as much as you like :-)

And, voila, it's no longer stuck at "Priority Only"!

Cheers,
Oli

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to fix this issue:

1. Goto **Settings**
2. Tap on **Sound & notification**
3. Tap on **Do not disturb**
4. Tap on **Priority only allows**
5. **Toggle any item on & off** and that will trigger DND to be off.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Long press power button > long press 'shut down' > reboot to safe mode > wait until your phone is ready to go.

Keep pressing volume down button until vibration mode > press once more for silent mode> press 'end now' to end do not disturb mode.

Once you are done, restart your phone.

Answer (score 1):

My phone was stuck at do not disturb sigh (a circle with minus sign), This is how i fixed it.

1. Press the volume button in your phone
2. Bring ringer volume to zero using volume button.
3. Press end now in do not disturb and it will go away.
4. Raise volume to normal after that.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have faced the same problem. How i solved was, i have pull down the volume button till silent and do not disturb mode shown as untill you turn off then i turned off it and increased volume to ringer.